# My laptop doesn't work sounds and HDMI drivers on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: lenovo, ubuntu-drivers

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and work fine two first week. Today I don't have any drivers, sounds and HDMI. My laptop lenovo ideapad 100 not have sounds and the HDMI doesn't work too suddenly.